# Finding out which of two words appears first in a string

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to determine which of two words ("ERROR" and choice between other loglevel such as "WARN" or "DEBUG") appears first in a string (extracted from log files), considering that it is not guaranteed that either of those words appears in the list of strings I am parsing.

If WARN appears first in the string before ERROR, it is a miss and should be ignored. Due to the nature of the issue, I tried with a regular expression and lookbehind, but it is also not common that either of those words is direct neighbours and also none of those words are the first word in the string. I also can't depend on log format, as there are many log format behind parsed.

The latest regular expression I tested to find the string I should ignore is:

`(?:(?!\\bERROR\\b).)*(INFO|WARN|TRACE|DEBUG).*`

The following strings should match:

- "Date DEBUG message"
- "@LGW Date WARN encapsulated message caused by
  ERROR exception message"

The following strings should match, as they shouldn't be skipped:

- "ERROR this is an exception"
- "Date {class} ERROR this error has been caused by INFO message"

That said, maybe using regular expression is the wrong approach and I should consider some other way, but I have no clue what this other way is like.

Here is the state of my code so far:

```
private boolean isIssue(String logEntry) {

        String miss = "(?:(?!\\bERROR\\b).)*(INFO|WARN|TRACE|DEBUG).*";

        Pattern missPattern = Pattern.compile(miss);
        Matcher missMatcher = missPattern.matcher(logEntry);

        // first check if the line should be declared "not issue" and thus ignored
        if (missMatcher.matches())
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (matchIssueList(logEntry))
        {
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: why use regex? why not just use old fashioned indexOf ?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Because I haven't considered it. Probably used to solve my issues too often with regexes. You know the expression "When all you have is an hammer, everything looks like a nail"

Comment: @ScaryWombat or yes, the reason might be because I'm trying to find the index of one word, compared to the index of a list of words... But it may still be better.

Comment: Could you please provide some code you tried?

Comment: @Maf I provided the code I'm using at the moment.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Please describe the business case. For me, it sounds you want to read the log level. In a log file, the log level should always be at the same position, so you can extract it directly.

Comment: @McPringle first there is quite a few log format intertwined, some propertiary, some third-party (apache), second I'm trying to get all the errors, but there were some messages referring other message, so I want to be skip each log entry where ERROR is not the first loglevel, without relying to any specific log format.

Comment: Have you considered using one of the many log parsing tools that are already written for this very purpose? Looks like an https://xyproblem.info/.

Answer (score 1):

You could use your pattern with an alternation, capturing only `ERROR` in capture group 1.

If group 1 exists, there was a match for example ERROR, but not preceded by either `INFO` `WARN` `TRACE` or `DEBUG`

```
^(?:(?:(?!\bERROR\b).)*\b(?:INFO|WARN|TRACE|DEBUG)\b|.*\b(ERROR)\b).*$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?:(?!\bERROR\b).)*` Match any char when directly at the right is not ERROR
  - `\b(?:INFO|WARN|TRACE|DEBUG)\b` Match any of the alternatives
  - `|` or
  - `.*\b(ERROR)\b` Match `ERROR` in the line
- `)` Close non capture group
- `.*` Match the rest of the line
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/spVaaF/1) and a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/fKKnPx)

As an example

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Ideone {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] strings = { 
                "Date DEBUG message",
                "@LGW Date WARN encapsulated message caused by ERROR exception message", 
                "ERROR this is an exception",
                "Date {class} ERROR this error has been caused by INFO message", 
        };

        for (String s : strings) {
            boolean isIssue = Ideone.isIssue(s);
            System.out.println(isIssue + " : " + s);
        }
    }

    private static boolean isIssue(String logEntry) {

        String miss = "^(?:(?:(?!\\bERROR\\b).)*\\b(?:INFO|WARN|TRACE|DEBUG)\\b|.*\\b(ERROR)\\b).*";
        Pattern missPattern = Pattern.compile(miss);
        Matcher missMatcher = missPattern.matcher(logEntry);

        if (missMatcher.matches()) {
            return null != missMatcher.group(1);
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Output

```
false : Date DEBUG message
false : @LGW Date WARN encapsulated message caused by ERROR exception message
true : ERROR this is an exception
true : Date {class} ERROR this error has been caused by INFO message
```

Answer (score 0):

`indexOf` is one approach, and the simplest.  You would take each `line`, then do a `line.indexOf("ERROR")` and `line.indexOf("WARN")`.  If either (a) the former is negative, or (b) the latter is non-negative and less than the former, then it is a miss.

For slight optimization, you may be able to run the WARN check first, then do an indexOf for ERROR on the substring/subsequence if the result was non-negative, else do it on the full string.  Perhaps substring is not going to win you any prizes, because that will create a brand new `String`...

---

Now, there **is** a further optimization, but it's probably not worth it.  It basically takes your string compares from "#compares for WARN + #compares for ERROR" down to "2 * MIN(#compares for WARN, #compares for ERROR)".

If that's a savings you feel you need, because your lines are very long + you are in time critical code + WARN often times appears way after ERROR but also enough times before ERROR that your false positives are annoying, then you can try the below.

Pseudocode follows:

```
// in a function/method returning boolean to indicate "skip", param 'line'

errorIdx = 0, warnIdx = 0
error = "ERROR", warn = "WARN"

for (idx = 0, idx < line.length(), idx++) {
   char c = line.charAt(idx);
   if (c == warn.charAt(warnIdx)) warnIdx++;
   else if (c == warn.charAt(0)) warnIdx = 1;
   else warnIdx = 0;

   if (c == error.charAt(errorIdx)) errorIdx++;
   else if (c == error.charAt(0)) errorIdx = 1;
   else errorIdx = 0;

   // if we hit the end of "WARN" or "ERROR", leave immediately
   if (warnIdx == warn.length()) return false;
   if (errorIdx == error.length()) return true;
}
return false;
```

This works for your specific strings, but if you want to generalize it watch out for corner cases.  The `else if` is needed since we are not stopping the outer loop's `idx` from moving even when a match index is reset.  The reason we don't just stop the outer loop (e.g. change to a `while` and not increment `idx`) is because inside are 2 string compares, and you'd mess up one of them by doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Used regexs:

```
Pattern validPattern = Pattern.compile("\\bERROR\\b");
Pattern invalidPattern = Pattern.compile("\\b(?:INFO|WARN|TRACE|DEBUG)\\b.*?\\bERROR\\b");
```

Regexs in testbench and context:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Match is false:
    String input1 = "Date DEBUG message";
    String input2 = "@LGW Date WARN encapsulated message caused by ERROR exception message";

    // Match is true:
    String input3 = "ERROR this is an exception";
    String input4= "Date {class} ERROR this error has been caused by INFO message";


    List<String> inputs = Arrays.asList(input1, input2, input3, input4);

    Pattern validPattern = Pattern.compile("\\bERROR\\b");
    Pattern invalidPattern = Pattern.compile("\\b(?:INFO|WARN|TRACE|DEBUG)\\b.*?\\bERROR\\b");

    for (String input : inputs) {
        Matcher validMatcher = validPattern.matcher(input);
        Matcher invalidMatcher = invalidPattern.matcher(input);
        if(validMatcher.find() && !invalidMatcher.find()) {
            System.out.printf("This input is a match: '%s'.%n", input);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
This input is a match: 'ERROR this is an exception'.
This input is a match: 'Date {class} ERROR this error has been caused by INFO message'.
```